# Unable to find the source of an exception and what an exception it is

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, exception, logging

I have a python scraper on a server run regularly by cron. Sometimes it crashes, but I can't figure out what makes it crash and where it crashes because there's nothing related to an exception in the logs: neither a mention an error, no stacktrace. The logger is setup this way:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename="log.log", level=logging.INFO)
```

But in case of exception, it must be logged into the log anyway, isn't that so?

The question is, how can I find the source of the exception.

Comment: change log level to logging.DEBUG. This will print more information in the log file. Which will help you debug better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Python module to record the crash information is called `traceback`. Essentially, you need to install a catch-all exception handler at the very top level, and call `logging.error(traceback.format_exc())`.

```
"""The main module of the application that is called from the command
line or cron"""
import logging
import traceback

# import other modules used by this one
import some_stuff

class A:
    # whatever
def foo():
    # whatever

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(filename="/path/log.log", level=logging.INFO)
    try:
        # The top-level logic of the program goes here
        var = A()
        foo()
        # whatever
    except:
        # This a catch-all exception handler for any stuff that was not
        # not properly handled by the program logic.
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
```

Note that if you are using Python extension modules implemented in C/C++, and there is a crash inside such a module (e.g., a segmentation fault), the program will still crash silently. No easy way around for this.

Comment: `logging.error(traceback.format_exc())` -- I'm unable to call it because I'm unaware of the source of the exception

Comment: You don't need to know the source. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: You don't understand. I have a big program. where should I insert "try except" if I don't know where it crashes?

Comment: You should insert it into the main module, the one that is called from the `cron` job. You sandwich the main loop of the module with `try: ... except:` .

Comment: expanded the example

Comment: one again: it's a big application.

Comment: I mean, I've heard that it's not recommended to catch all errors at once.

Comment: You are right that deep inside the call stack catching all the exceptions is a bad idea, because it may conceal errors. However, at the very top level there is nothing to lose: the alternative is a crash without logged data. The size of the application does not matter, you catch the exceptions only once at the very top.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to check what exception you are getting.

```
try:
   #the code which may throw exception
except Exception as e:
   #log the exception over here.
```